# Cassandra commit log clarification

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have read over several documents regarding the Cassandra commit log and, to me, there is conflicting information regarding this "structure(s)". The diagram shows that when a write occurs, Cassandra writes to the memtable and commit log. The confusing part is where this commit log resides.

The diagram that I've seen over-and-over shows the commit log on disk. However, if you do some more reading, they also talk about a commit log buffer in memory - and that piece of memory is flushed to disk every 10 seconds.

DataStax Documentation states: 
"When a write occurs, Cassandra stores the data in a memory structure called memtable, and to provide configurable durability, it also appends writes to the commit log buffer in memory. This buffer is flushed to disk every 10 seconds".

Nowhere in their diagram do they show a memory structure called a commit log buffer. They only show the commit log residing on disk.

It also states:
"When a write occurs, Cassandra stores the data in a structure in memory, the memtable, and also appends writes to the commit log on disk."

So I'm confused by the above. Is it written to the commit log memory buffer, which is eventually flushed to disk (which I would assume is also called the "commit log"), or is it written to the memtable and commit log on disk?

Apache's documentation states this:
"Instead, like other modern systems, Cassandra provides durability by appending writes to a commitlog first. This means that only the commitlog needs to be fsync'd, which, if the commitlog is on its own volume, obviates the need for seeking since the commitlog is append-only. Implementation details are in ArchitectureCommitLog.

Cassandra's default configuration sets the commitlog_sync mode to periodic, causing the commitlog to be synced every commitlog_sync_period_in_ms milliseconds, so you can potentially lose up to that much data if all replicas crash within that window of time."

What I have inferred from the Apache statement is that ONLY because of the asynchronous nature of writes (acknowledgement of a cache write) could you lose data (it even states you can lose data if all replicas crash before it is flushed/sync'd).

I'm not sure what I can infer from the DataStax documentation and diagram as they've mentioned two different statements regarding the commit log - one in memory, one on disk.

Can anyone clarify, what I consider, a poorly worded and conflicting set of documentation?

I'll assume there is a commit log buffer, as they both reference it (yet DataStax doesn't show it in the diagram). How and when this is managed, I think, is a key to understand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally when explaining the write path, the commit log is characterized as a file - and it's true the commit log is the on-disk storage mechanism that provides durability.  The confusion is introduced when going deeper and the part about buffer cache and having to issue fsyncs is introduced.  The reference to "commit log buffer in memory" is talking about OS buffer cache, not a memory structure in Cassandra. You can see in the [code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLog.java#L272) that there's not a separate in-memory structure for the commit log, but rather the mutation is serialized and written to a [file-backed buffer](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegment.java#L145).

Cassandra comes with two strategies for managing fsync on the commit log.

```
commitlog_sync 
    (Default: periodic) The method that Cassandra uses to acknowledge writes in milliseconds:
    periodic: (Default: 10000 milliseconds [10 seconds])
    Used with commitlog_sync_period_in_ms to control how often the commit log is synchronized to disk. Periodic syncs are acknowledged immediately.

    batch: (Default: disabled)note
    Used with commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms (Default: 2 ms) to control how long Cassandra waits for other writes before performing a sync. When using this method, writes are not acknowledged until fsynced to disk.
```

The `periodic` offers better performance at the cost of a small increase in the chance that data can be lost.  The `batch` setting guarantees durability at the cost of latency.

Comment: So help me understand what happens when a write occurs. Cassandra acknowledges a write when the consistency is met, let's say 2. Does that mean it has made it to the commit log on disk, or in memory. In other words, for things to be "guaranteed", do you have to wait until it's flushed (e.g. default of 10000 ms, or 10 seconds)? From what I'm reading, until the memory is sync'd, you have the possibility to lose data, in our example, up to 10 seconds of it - but the acknowledgement comes quickly due to memory receiving the data (on all replicas that meet the consistency level).

Comment: For a write to be acknowledged, it must have made it into the commit log and memtable.  To achieve consistency level 2, this must happen on 2 nodes.  I think your question centers around this - what does it mean to "make it to the commit log"?  By default, this means the write has been issued to the filesystem but potentially not fsync'd to the actual disk. If you need absolute durability then you can change commitlog_sync to batch at the cost of higher latency.

Comment: @AndrewWeaver I have a small doubt. You mention in your answer above that there is a chance the data can be lost. I don't understand that. If we have info about a write in the commit log and we assume a node goes down before it is fsnyced to actual disk from commit log, wouldn't the node replay the commit log when restarted and recover the data ?

Comment: @Vinay, you just answered your own question.  If a node goes down before it's fsynced then it's not actually on the disk.  If it's not on the disk the node can't read it from the commit log.

Comment: For future readers, [here](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Durability) is some (old) reference.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the distinction between "appending to the commit log" without fsync'ing, and NOT yet having appended to the commit log, seems artificial and irrelevant, and only causing confusion. If all we care about is whether it's durable or not, fsync is all that matters. Is there a reason why this distinction is made? Perhaps that the write made it through all the application logic without error?