# Can I write to Redis (setup with AOF) with safety. Like having a GO-NOGO commit

Tags: redis

When I write to REDIS (set up with an AOF) can I be assured that my data is persisted to the AOF correctly by the time my overall write has completed?

ie:  I want to make sure my write is persistent (like a successful commit) before I continue on in my processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `appendfsync always`, then every write will be persisted and flushed (OS-level fsync) before command returns. However, note that:

- after OS level fsync there is a hardware level fsync, which is done by device driver and you have no control over it. If you care a lot about data safety, choose enterprise grade devices which have capacitors that allow emergency fsync in case of power failure.
- `appendfsync always` is slow compared to other Redis modes. You can peek at numbers a bit here: [aof fsync vs cassandra LSM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50482820/78569)