# Synch delay when writing to Cassandra with two data centers and LOCAL_QUORUM

Tags: cassandra

The motivation of this question is to follow from this great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506734/cassandra-commit-log-clarification). I finally got some clarification of what they mean from eventual consistency in Cassandra. [Andrew Weaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931573/andrew-weaver) explained what happens with the commit log very clearly. Now I would like to find out what happens when you have two data centers and you use a consistency of LOCAL_QUORUM. This is the scenario: I just finished writing to data center one and commit log was flushed/sync'd to disk and two other replicas also were synchronized. When would the writing to the second data center would take placed?
I imagine that one of the instances would initiate the syncing process but there will be a delay. What is that delayed? Also if the data one center goes down before syncing it will not be available in data cente r two. But what happens if the same row is written in data in data center two. How does the row gets reconcile?
The same question if data center one goes down the middle of the syncing process? When would the data be consistent and if there is any gotchas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to think that in your case the replication to the second datacenter is done in an async way. The delay in general is in milliseconds. 
If the datacenter one goes down, then you write the same row to the second datacenter, it like two different writes, so different timestamps and the last write will win (in case of different data of course). reconciliation will happen during repair, or read repair or also if you will read with a consistency level ALL.

This is a very good article by Ryan Svihla, explaining the subjet with different cases :

https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-how-many-nodes-are-talked-to-with-quorum-also-should-i-use-it-98074e75d7d5

I hope this helps.

Comment: it's not really an async replication - coordinator node writes to all replicas at the same time, consistency level just defines how many answers we want to wait for: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntClientRequestsMultiDCWrites.html

Comment: What I am missing is when the write to the second DC start and by what. Is the coordinator that just wrote to local DC and is it done after return the answer to the client or before? is it one of the replicas that was written to and is it done asynchronous?

Comment: @Fabio The coordinator returns the answer to the client as soon as it gets sufficient responses to meet the configured consistency level.  So if you write at LOCAL_ONE, it waits until it gets a single response from a replica in the LOCAL data center, but the writes to all of the other replicas are still happening.

Comment: Just to clarify according to the picture that Alex Ott provided the coordinator is the one that would write to the second DC as part of the same request even if the response to the client has already been sent, right?

Comment: There are some synchronous actions, other are asynchronous. Writing to a distant(from cordinator point of view) datacenter with CL local_quorum should be considered as asynchronous because all nodes in the distant data center are not involved in your consistency level , detail in : https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra/data-replication-in-nosql-databases-explained